# Error when updating value at SQL database

Tags: mysql, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I want to updating data at my database SQL with VB.NET. But I'm facing the problem.
For more specific, The data will updated when the Barcode Textbox is same as at Datagridview column. Here's my code

```
    Private Sub nHarga_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As 
    System.EventArgs) Handles nHarga.TextChanged
    If cBarcode.Text <> "" Then
        Dim isi As Integer
        isi = Me.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
        With DataGridView1.Rows.Item(isi)
            If .Cells(0).Value = cBarcode.Text Then
                Try
                    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("update transaksi_sementara set jumlah = jumlah + 1 where barcode = '" & cBarcode.Text & "'", dbkon)
                    dbreader.Close()
                    If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery = 1 Then
                        Call bersih()
                        Call tampil()
                    End If
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
                End Try
            Else
                Try
                    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("insert into transaksi_sementara values('" & cBarcode.Text & "','" & cNamaBarang.Text & "','1','" & nHarga.Text & "','" & nHarga.Text & "')", dbkon)
                    dbreader.Close()
                    If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery = 1 Then
                        Call bersih()
                        Call tampil()
                    End If
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
                End Try
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Your code is quite confusing. Why are you calling `dbreader.Close()`? Also you need to open the connection to do anything with the command. You should also use parameters to avoid SQL injection and to minimise syntax errors.